# Does React perform a deep compare or a shallow compare in render method?

Tags: reactjs

React Document says

> React.PureComponent's shouldComponentUpdate() only shallowly compares
>   the objects.

Does it mean the Component will do a deep compare unless we make it a PureComponent ?

Comment: Why the downvote ? There's no code to be posted for this question.

Comment: because the stackoverflow community is focussing more on closing and downvoting questions that might have been asked before instead of helping programmers. LE: or questions that might be off topic

Answer (score 6):

No, by default `Component` will re-render even if its props stay the same (**by doing no compare at all**), unless you decide to implement your own `shouldComponentUpdate`.

From [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html):

> render() will not be invoked if shouldComponentUpdate() returns false.

and then:

> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or
>   state are being received. Defaults to true.

Comment: How does `Component` decide to re-render if its props stay the same? Triggered by parent component re-render?

Comment: @DrakeXiang unless it's `PureComponent`, it will construct a VirtualDOM tree on every parent change. If there was no change in component's props it will see that there are no differences in new and old VirtualDOM trees and as a result it won't perform any actual DOM update.

Comment: @pwolaq, Then how redux connected component would trigger a render on store change when parent not been changed? Then component should do a deep comparison I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Because of missing rep i will add this as a comment above from pwolaq:

You can really take advantage of using `PureComponent` when you use an immutable data structure as your app's data. When an immutable data structure is changed, we get a different object. Thats the reason a shallow compare (which is very cheap to process) will quickly detect changes.

Using `redux` in conjunction with `seamless-immutable` for example lets you build applications that only rerender specific components bound to data that is nested in a deep application data object are bound to updated without ever having to implement `shouldComponentUpdate()`